# How to add a customer in Shopify API?

Tags: python, shopify

When I try to add a new customer with the following code:

```
new_customer = shopify.Customer()
new_customer.first_name = "andres"
new_customer.last_name = "cepeda"
success = new_customer.save()
```

And it works. However when I tried to add another fields such a address or company,

```
new_customer = shopify.Customer()
new_customer.first_name = "andres"
new_customer.last_name = "cepeda"
new_customer.company = "my company"
new_customer.address = "cll 25 - 27"
success = new_customer.save()
```

It didn't work.

Comment: Please explain what "It didn't work" means. Do you get an exception? If so, what is it? Do you get no exception and your record is simply not created? Being detailed in what is not working helps provide necessary context for readers to know how to help.

Comment: The response just its true or false, true when the customer is successfully created.

Comment: Do you have any server logs you can reference? There is no way to know what is really happening on your end without more information. There could be a unique constraint violation with trying to add a new customer because the name is the same? It's all speculation at this point.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with the OP's code and neither of the answers above address **both** issues here so I'll add my answer.

First issue:
In order to add the address to the new_customer, you have to use "addresses" property, not "address". He was missing the "es" at the end (plural). This is because the addresses property is a list. Even if you only want to add 1 address, you must include it in list brackets as shown below.

```
new_customer = shopify.Customer()
  new_customer.first_name = "andres"
  new_customer.last_name = "cepeda"
  new_customer.addresses = [{"address1": "123 Oak st", "city": "Ottawa", "phone": "9876543210", "company": "Apple"}]
  new_customer.default_address = {"address1": "123 Oak st", "city": "Ottawa", "phone": "9876543210", "company": "Apple"}
  new_customer.save()
```

You can set the default address by using a dictionary directly. This is because this field is always going to be only 1 address so there is no need to use list format (and will error out if you try).

Second Issue:
The second issue is that the OP is trying to set "company" field directly on the Customer object (new_customer). The company field is part of the address, not the customer directly. As shown in my example above, include company as one of the address fields and it will work.

See docs for reference: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/customers/customer#what-you-can-do-with-customer

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
custo = shopify.Customer()
      custo.first_name = "andres"
      custo.last_name = "cepeda"
      custo.addresses = [{"address1": "123 Oak st", "city": "Ottawa", "phone": "9876543210"}]
      custo.save()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
address = { address1: 'Some address', city: 'Ottawa', province: 'ON', zip: 'K1P 0C2' }

new.customer.addresses = [address]
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer].